# Regular expression for matching a variety of types of numbered lists in R

Tags: regex, r, list, gsub

I have a set of files with (potentially) different kinds of ordered lists in them. I'd like to collapse any list instances into paragraph text, and strip the # out.  I.e.

```
1. Hello
(a) world
ii) 3000
This isn't in the list.
```

Would become:

```
Hello world 3000.
This isn't in the list.
```

I can also imagine cases where it would be useful to extract such lists into a separate R object (e.g. we might want to take a text, create a list of lists storing each list item). (i.e., assuming concurrent list items are in the same list, the previous items would become 3 items in a list).

There's some guidance on doing this in `Python` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127949/regular-expression-for-matching-a-variety-of-types-of-numbered-lists) but I'd like to know how to manipulate such lists in `R`.

So far my attempts are pretty crude, e.g. building on the unordered list case `gsub("(\r?\n|\r)\\*", " ", stri1)`

Comment: Try `gsub("(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.\\s+", "", text, perl=T)` if you read the text as one string.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew so that works for  "x." based lists, I've just updated the example per the linked Python page, I'm also interested in other types of list format, specifically (x) and x) notations.  So we have the a/i/1/1.1 numbering, plus (), ), and . formatting.

Comment: So this takes it a bit further, but the (x) remain, and on the '1.1' style, the second digit isn't deleted:

`gsub("\\r(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.|\\r(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)|\\n(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.|\\n(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)", "", test, perl=T)`

Comment: Resolved the 1.1 issue:

`gsub("\\r(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.+[a-zA-Z0-9]|\\r(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.|\\r(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)|\\n(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.|\\n(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)", "", test, perl=T)`

Comment: Ok this lets me collapse all of them:
`gsub("\\r(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.+[a-zA-Z0-9]|\\r(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.|\\r(?m)\n?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)|\\n(?m)\r?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.|\\n(?m)\r?^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)|\\n(?m)\\r?^\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)|\\r(?m)\\n?^\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)", "", test, perl=T)`

Reading them into lists would also be fun (but that's definitely beyond my ability right now)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the file in as one string, you can solve that with

```
txt = "1. Hello\r\n(a) world\r\nii) 3000\r\nThis isn't in the list."
txt = gsub("(?m)[\r\n]*^(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*|\\(?[a-z]+\\))\\s+", " ", txt, perl=T)
lst = strsplit(txt, "\r?\n")
```

Output:

```
> txt
[1] "1. Hello world 3000\r\nThis isn't in the list."
> lst
[[1]]
[1] "1. Hello world 3000"     "This isn't in the list."
```

The regex is

```
(?m)[\r\n]*^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*|\(?[a-z]+\))\s+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qK8nH2/2)

The `(?m)` forces `^` to match line start position, `[\r\n]*` matches zero or more `\n` or `\r` characters, `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*|\(?[a-z]+\))` matches either integer numbers or digits separated with dots, or one or more letters enclosed with and optional `(` and obligatory `)`. The `\s+` matches one or more whitespace symbols. **If the letters/Roman numbers can be uppercase, replace `(?m)` with `(?mi)`**.

Comment: Thanks, I think the list I was anticipating would result in:
[[1]]
[1] Hello
[2] world
[3] 3000

Any subsequent char-lists would create new lists. `Gsub` to create consistent list types (e.g. all 1. 2. 3., etc.) is probably sensible, and then I'd forgotten about `strsplit` which could read in \n[0-9] or something